# Azure DevOps Pipeline - Updating BuildNumber

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have attempted to update the build number in Azure DevOps Pipelines for quite some time now, and looked through various stackoverflow questions and documentation, and I simply cannot figure out how to fix my problem.

The Build Number I would like to set would be: `$(year:yy)$(DayOfYear)$(rev:.r)`.

This apparently works on pipelines using the graphical interface (The pipelines were not made by me)

**What I have tried so far:**

```
- task: UpdateBuildNumber@0
  inputs:
    buildNumber: '$(year:yy)$(DayOfYear)$(rev:.r)'
```

```
Write-Host "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$(year:yy)$(DayOfYear)$(rev:.r)"
```

And a couple of variations of those as well. Each time, I get the error:

> ##[error]TF209010: The build number format $(year:yy)$(DayOfYear)$(rev:.r) contains invalid character(s), is too
> long, or ends with '.'. The maximum length of a build number is 255
> characters. Characters which are not allowed include '"', '/', ':',
> '<', '>', '', '|', '?', '@', and '*'.

I have tried making variables for each of the dates, and using the variables instead, but that does not work either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It because all those variables are available only if you give it in the `name:` in your YAML, not in other tasks.

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/run-number?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml):

> The following table shows how each token is resolved based on the previous example. You can use these tokens only to define a run number; they don't work anywhere else in your pipeline.

So, the only option it just to configure the `name: $(year:yy)$(DayOfYear)$(rev:.r)`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Hope you have a wonderful day!!